# New chaincode container is not launched after upgrade

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I followed the instructions to upgrade chaincode from [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/chaincode_lifecycle.html#upgrade-a-chaincode). I executed all the steps successfully. I was able to see the committed chaincode information by the command `peer lifecycle chaincode querycommitted --channelID mychannel --name mycc`. The docker images are also created for new chaincode but the containers were not launched. The `chaincode invoke` and `query` commands also give old results.

I also tried deleting the old chaincode from peers and removing old chaincode containers, but it starts the old chaincode containers again when I run `chaincode query` or `invoke` command.

I use `peer lifecycle chaincode` commands in Hyperledger Fabric 2.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. The problem was with the value of `--package-id` option in `peer lifecycle chaincode approveformyorg` command. I used the `approveForMyOrg` function in `utils.sh` file that comes in `first-network` directory in `fabric-samples`. The mistake was I passed the `PACKAGE_ID` from the results of `queryInstalled` function which had all the installed chaincode packages. I made a following change in the `sed` command in that function.

```
PACKAGE_ID=`sed -n "/$CCNAME_$VERSION/{s/^Package ID: //; s/, Label:.*$//; p;}" log.txt`
```